# How to apply a style to each row?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to make a data log out of an Excel spreadsheet I have imported with the following rows : `Date, Time, Urgence, Description`. What I want to do is to arrive to the following result that I would print on an html page :

```
20/01 | 17:00 | Text description here1 <- In red when the the "Urgence" row is equal to 1
17/01 | 11:00 | Text description here2 <- In orange when the the "Urgence" row is equal to 2                                                                            
16/01 | 16:32 | Text description here3 <- In green when the the "Urgence" row is equal to 3
```

Each log should only fit on one line, no more.

What I did was :

```
import pandas as pd

file = r"..\test.xlsx"

try:
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    #print(df)

except OSError:
    print("Impossible to read", file)

test =
    df['Date'].map(str) + ' | ' \
    + df['Time'].map(str) + ' | ' \
    + df['Description'].map(str) + ' | ' \
    + '\n'
    print(test)
```

The output is :

> 20/01 | 17:00 | Text description here1 17/01 | 11:00 | Text
> description here2 16/01 | 16:32 | Text description here3 <- In orange
> when the the "Urgence" is equal to 3

My questions are :

1. How do you jump a line for each row printed ? As you can see, the results are all stuck together (Edit : even with the newline '\n' added).
2. How do you apply a style when a condition is met, I believe there should be a function that iterates through each line to check if the row `"Urgence" == 1 or 2 or 3` then adjust the style accordingly but I don't really see how to do it.
3. Edit : Besides, I am also looking for way for each log to fit
   only on one line, it should never overflow on the line beneath.

Thank you.

Comment: You should narrow your question. Divide your problem in chunks. Because just put the output in a HTML is a whole problem by itself. Are you using Flask, django, bootstrap?

Comment: if you display on HTML then you should use `<br>` instead of `\n` or you should use `df.to_html()` - and it may have options to set styles or colors to every row.

Comment: you should see documentation for [.to_string()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) and [.to_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) because they can get function as `formatter` and it may set different format for different values.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I am currently trying to see how to get 1 line from the file displayed on 1 line of the html with to.string(), but so far it's unsuccesful, the output still does what is shown above, lines are stuck together :/ I am not using any framework.